# amcharts integration SCRIPT1002 Syntax error in IE 11

Tags: typescript, internet-explorer-11, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm facing an issue in loading an integrated amchart with typescript app in IE 11.

App node module versions

"@types/node": "^10.9.4",

"typescript": "2.9.1",

"@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.13",

"babel-core": "^6.26.3",

"babel-loader": "^7.1.5",

I'm getting the following error when executing this line of code in IE 11.

```
const chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);
```

The error is

```
**SCRIPT1002 : syntax error**
```

I have tried adding support to arrow function as the error is happening for arrow function

```
/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = (function(f) {
  let delta = f;
  let compare = f;

  if (f.length === 1) {
    delta = (d, x) => f(d) - x; // Error Here
    compare = ascendingComparator(f);
  }
})
```

I've tried

1. installing `@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions` and specifying it as a plugin in babelrc.
2. In `tsconfig.json` changed the target to es5
3. Imported the necessary polyfills in `polyfills.ts` file
4. added rules to support in `webpack.config`

Also most of the solutions in stackoverflow I tried.
But still this error is not resolved . Could you please help me on this

Comment: Did you try to add the `core-js` polyfill? If not, I suggest you add it by running the `npm install core-js @types/core-js regenerator-runtime` command and try to add `import "core-js/stable";` at the top of the TypeScript / JavaScript code. This must be put before everything else, or it won't work! Please see [Polyfill for older browsers](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/using-typescript-or-es6/#Polyfill_for_older_browsers).

Comment: Tried this. But not working

Comment: Does it show any other error after adding the `core-js` polyfill? If yes, please inform us about it. Are you trying to use **Force Directed Tree plugin**? If yes, it is not supported in the IE browser.

Comment: It doesn't show core-js error because I exluded it from compiling with babel. At present I'm using only geographical map

Comment: Just for testing purposes, can you try to remove other polyfills and only add the `core-js` polyfill? To see whether it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, You need to install this version

```
npm i @amcharts/amcharts4@4.3.5
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@amcharts/amcharts4/v/4.3.5

this version works for me